# How to unlock native script in netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I need to know if I can unlock a native script in netsuite or copy this script. I need to modify this script because it is a view PDF.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you will not be able to view this as this is set at the bundle level. If the script is locked and the script file also cannot be viewed, there is no way to review the contents of the .js file. This is to by design because businesses may not want their customers to review the source code of the scripts. If you want to see the contents of the script you can always reach out to the bundle owner!

More information can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3380255.html